# C++ Will virtual functions still work if I upcast a derived object to its base type

Tags: c++

Consider the following:

- B inherits from A and overrides the print function.
- A has a static function which takes a void*, casts it to A and calls the virtual print function.
- If the void* was originally a B will it call A::print or B::print?

  ```
  #include <iostream>

  class A {
  public:
          static void w(void *p) {

                  A *a = reinterpret_cast<A*>(p);
                  a->print();
          }

          virtual void print() {
             std::cout << "A"  << std::endl;
          }
  };

  class B : public A {

  public:
          void print() {
             std::cout << "B"  << std::endl;
          }
  };

  int main () {
          B b;
          A::w(&b);
  }
  ```

This prints B for me.

It seems that the void* which has been casted to an A still knows about B's overridden print function. The reason why is not immediately clear.

Can someone explain to me if this is behavior that I can rely on or if it is just some fluke that works because it is a small example (like how returning a reference to a local variable won't always segfault in small programs).

Comment: +1, I *think* it's *undefined behaviour* to use `reinterpret_cast` to change pointer types, even if they are related by inheritance. But I am not certain. There are other solutions for your specific case, but I suspect you're aware of those and that's not the point of your question.

Comment: Why doesn't `w` take `A*`?

Comment: @Pixelchemist I'm working with C callbacks so it will always give me a void*.

Comment: To get well-defined behaviour, convert to `A*` before converting to `void*`. (Your example happens to "work" for you because the `A` subobject has the same address as the complete object. That won't necessarily be the case, especially if there are multiple base classes.)

Comment: can't you use `dynamic_cast` and check for a `nullptr`?

Comment: @OMGtechy: `dynamic_cast` only works when both static type and dynamic type are polymorphic.  But `void` isn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Virtual functions are usually resolved by an implicit `vtable`. This is basically an array of function pointers for every virtual function in the class hierarchy. The compiler adds it as a "hidden member" to your class. When calling a virtual function, the corresponding entry in the vtable is called.

Now, when you create a class of type `B`, it implicitly has the B-vtable stored in the object. Casts do not affect this table.

Hence, when you cast your `void *` to `A`, the original vtable (of class `B`) is present, which points to `B::print`.

Note that this is implementation defined behaviour, and the standard does not guarantee anything about this. But most compilers will act like this

Comment: Except that the calling code looks up the v-table according to the layout of `A`... and there's no guarantee that this matches the layout of `B`.  In many cases it doesn't.  (Others have mentioned multiple and virtual inheritance, but the Standard doesn't limit layout differences to these two reasons)

Comment: This isn't implementation-defined, it's just undefined.

Answer (score 8):

your code has **undefined behavior**

**§ 5.2.10 Reinterpret cast**

> 7 Converting a prvalue of type “pointer to T1” to the
>   type “pointer to T2” (where T1 and T2 are object types and where the alignment requirements of T2 are no stricter than those of T1) and back to its original type yields the original pointer value. **The result of any other such pointer conversion is unspecified.**

Comment: +1 thought so: was waiting for some good chap to take the time!

Comment: While this is correct from a standard POV, the more interesting question really would be if there is *any known* platform where this *doesn't* work.

Comment: @MartinBa No, it wouldn't. That's not an interesting question at all.

Comment: @molbdnilo - Yeah Right. What actually works and what not isn't interesting at all.

Comment: @MartinBa It's undefined. It's as interesting as division by zero is in maths.

Comment: @molbdnilo If every implementation does something different than the standard specifies, guess which is more interesting? Anyway, a more interesting question is how he can accomplish what he's trying to achieve.

Comment: Undefined behavior? I guess I'll backup my hard drive before running the code.

Comment: @MartinBa practically all of them - if you count the multiple or virtual inheritance in. In practice even if there are no such platforms now it does not mean that there won't be in the future. Compilers often use undefined behaviour to know what won't happen and [eliminate some code](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/918) (or reorder it etc.). So even if it looks like it should not break it might in the future via valid transformations.

Comment: @molbdnilo I find your response to Martin Ba's original "interesting question" pretty spectacularly pedantic; true, undefined behavior should *never* be used, but why would you respond so negatively to someone simply wondering how various implementations actually behave? Even if Martin Ba doesn't ever *write* code with this undefined behavior in it, it still may be useful to know what *can* happen with such code, since *other* programmers might introduce errors this way.

Comment: Knowing about how different implementations handle particular undefined behaviors could, for instance, help debug problems introduced when code is migrated to a new platform (since other programmers may have relied on undefined behavior that happened to work on the old platform).

Answer (score 2):

First of all your `reinterpret_cast` is undefined.
If you pass a `A*` to `w` it will be defined.

```
A * p = new B;
A::w(p);
delete p;
```

I suggest to use `static_cast<A*>(p)` instead, if `w` is always called using `A*`.

If you have a defined cast to `void*` and back the memory address stays constant.
So `a` inside your `w` will be a valid `A*` if you pass a valid `A*` to `w` first.

The question why the program knows how to handle the call is related to a mechanic called "Virtual Table".

*Note: This may be different for different compilers. I'll talk about how Visual Studio seems to handle it.*

To give you a somewhat rough idea for simple inheritance:

The compiler will compile 2 `print` functions in your code: 
`A::print` (**i.e. at address `X`**) and `B::print` (**i.e. at address `Y`**).

The *real* memory footprint of a class containing virtual function (i.e.

```
struct A
{
  void print (void);
  size_t x;
};
struct B : A
{
  void print (void);
  size_t y;
};
```

) will be somewhat like

```
struct Real_A
{
  void * vtable;
  size_t x;
};
struct Real_B : Real_A
{
  size_t y;
};
```

Furthermore there will be two so called virtual tables, one for each class containing virtual functions or having a base class with virtual functions.

You can think of the vtable as a structure holding the "real" address for each function.

Upon compilation the compiler will create Vtables for each class (`A` and `B`):
Each instance of A will have `vtable = <Address of A Vtable>` while each instance of `B` will have `vtable = <Address of B Vtable>`.

At runtime if a virtual function is called the program will look up the "real" address for the function from the Vtable which is stored at the address which is first element to each object of `A` or `B`

**The following code is non-standard and not sane**
... but it may give you an idea though...

```
#include <iostream>
struct A 
{
  virtual void print (void) { std::cout << "A called." << std::endl; }
  size_t x;
};

struct B : A 
{
  void print (void) { std::cout << "B called." << std::endl; }
};
// "Real" memory layout of A
struct Real_A
{
  void * vtable;
  size_t x_value;
};
// "Real" memory layout of B
struct Real_B : Real_A
{
  size_t y_value;
};
// "Pseudo virtual table structure for classes with 1 virtual function"
struct VT
{
  void * func_addr;
};

int main (void) 
{
  A * pa = new A;
  pa->x = 15;
  B * pb = new B;
  pb->x = 20;
  A * pa_b = new B;
  pa_b->x = 25;
  // reinterpret addrress of A and B objects as Real_A and Real_B
  Real_A& ra(*(Real_A*)pa);
  Real_B& rb(*(Real_B*)pb);
  // reinterpret addrress of B object through pointer to A as Real_B
  Real_B& rb_a(*(Real_B*)pa_b);
  // Print x_values to know whether we meet the class layout
  std::cout << "Value of ra.x_value = " << ra.x_value << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Value of rb.x_value = " << rb.x_value << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Value of rb.x_value = " << rb_a.x_value << std::endl;
  // Print vtable addresses
  std::cout << "VT of A through A*: " << ra.vtable << std::endl;
  std::cout << "VT of B through B*: " << rb.vtable << std::endl;
  std::cout << "VT of B through A*: " << rb_a.vtable << std::endl;
  // Reinterpret memory pointed to by the vtable address as VT objects
  VT& va(*(VT*)ra.vtable);
  VT& vb(*(VT*)rb.vtable);
  VT& vb_a(*(VT*)rb_a.vtable);
  // Print addresses of functions in the vtable
  std::cout << "FA of A through A*: " << va.func_addr << std::endl;
  std::cout << "FA of B through B*: " << vb.func_addr << std::endl;
  std::cout << "FA of B through A*: " << vb_a.func_addr << std::endl;

  delete pa;
  delete pb;
  delete pa_b;

  return 0;
}
```

Visual Studio 2013 output:

```
 Value of ra.x_value = 15
Value of rb.x_value = 20
Value of rb.x_value = 25
VT of A through A*: 00D9DC80
VT of B through B*: 00D9DCA0
VT of B through A*: 00D9DCA0
FA of A through A*: 00D914B0
FA of B through B*: 00D914AB
FA of B through A*: 00D914AB
```

gcc-4.8.1 output:

```
Value of ra.x_value = 15
Value of rb.x_value = 20
Value of rb.x_value = 25
VT of A through A*: 0x8048f38
VT of B through B*: 0x8048f48
VT of B through A*: 0x8048f48
FA of A through A*: 0x8048d40
FA of B through B*: 0x8048cc0
FA of B through A*: 0x8048cc0
```

https://ideone.com/iKyBB3

Note: No matter whether you access a B object through `A*` or `B*`, you'll find the same vtable address first and you'll find the same address contained in the vtable as well.

Answer (score 0):

reinterpret_cast cannot work, if you consider how multiple inheritance is implemented in C++.

Basically, when casting around between related types, with multiple inheritance, a cast might involve adding an offset. Hence without knowing the source and destination type, the compiler cannot emit the correct instructions.

So, reinterpret casts are undoable for at least this usecase, hence they are defined as undefined.

The dangerous part here, even if you do not do multiple inheritance, is that modern compilers start to interpret this "undefined" behaviour as meaning that they can optimize the thing, it's containing block and so on away. Which is almost certainly valid by the C++ standard (undefined means exactly that, anything is fine), but can be a surprise to the developer, who tended to understand "undefined" as "the code output might not work in general".